# jQuery .hover not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

Hi What is wrong with my code here:

When I hover over #open #pull_down_content should be moving down the page from the header and when I move away from #open it should move back up. But when I test the code as soon as the page loads #pull_down_content moves down the screen before I even hover over it.

```
$(function() {

//Open on hover 
$('#open').hover((function(){
    $('#pull_down_content').animate({'top':'-0px'},1000);
})

//Close when not hovered
(function(){
    $('#pull_down_content').animate({'top':'-340px'},1000);

})
});
);
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+hover First result. Why you no Google?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try fixing your function like below,

```
$(function() {        
    $('#open').hover(function(){ //Open on hover 
        $('#pull_down_content').animate({'top':'-0px'},1000);
    },    
    function(){ //Close when not hovered
        $('#pull_down_content').animate({'top':'-340px'},1000);    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need a little fix

```
$('yourElement').hover(
   function(){
      // hover code
   }, function(){
      // unhover code 
   }
);
```